# Why two equal columns of two matrices have different means?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two tensors (12 x 128 x 10) samples. The second tensor contains some samples of the first tensor and other samples. Similar to that example with matrices:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6; 11 12 13 14 15 16]
B = [4 5 6 7 8 9; 14 15 16 17 18 19]
```

When I intersect of my two tensors, I get ~1080 values that are the same, which is expected since:

```
column 1 to 78 from tensor 2 = column 50 to 128 from tensor 1 
      tensor2 (:,1:78, 1:10) = tensor 1(:, 50:128, 1:10).
```

However, I do the mean of the two tensors in the third dimension

```
m1 = mean(tensor1, 3)
m2 = mean(tensor2, 3)
```

Then the values of the mean are different. I expect:

```
m2 (:, 1:78) = m1(:,50:128).
```

But the values are different. Why is this happening?

Comment: I don't see any mistakes in your code. Can you post a minimal 3D example that duplicates the problem? e.g. `tensor2(:,1:10,1:2)` and `tensor1(:,50:59,1:2)` ?

Comment: My bet: [Why is 24.0000 not equal to 24.0000 in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab)

Comment: what do you get when you type `max(max(abs(m2(:,1:78) - m1(:,50:128))))`